# Script on script (any other script language if you all have an idea)

Tags: sed

I have this script that will run automatically on 2nd of every month. This script will download all the file from `ftp` server by date (which 2nd of every month).

Currently i have one script which is that will download the file from `ftp` server and i want to create another script that will change the date inside the the first script.

I want to make both script run automatically.

1. download_script
2. change_date_script (i want to create this)

Example:

1. download_script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   test_text_*_20170102_*.csv*
   ```
2. change_date_script (to change the date `20170102`)

do u all have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: your question is really unreadable, but, i will answer from what i understood, please clear it up

Comment: The solution that Mhd Wissam Al-Roujoulah gave you is good, but the script in the question doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

To change the date in the first script you don't need another script, just make the date dynamic by calling `date` command with specific options.

In your case you can use:

```
date +"%Y%m%d"
```

This will return you the date in this format `20170110` so you can assign it to variable and do what ever you want like:

```
today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
touch test"$today".csv
```

this will create a file with name `test20170110.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Put a file in `/etc/cron.d/get2ndmonth` with this content:

```
59 23 02 * * joe echo "mget test_text_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)_*.csv" | ftp example.org
```

It will run every `2nd` of the month at `23:59` for user `joe`.

(Please edit your original question if it is unclear)